# How to get reference to function in array if you know only the name of function?

Tags: javascript

lets say I have array of functions such as `[ function f1{}, function f2{}]` and I know that the function I want to get a reference too is called "f2", so that I can remove it from the array, how would I go about it? I tried using the object that contains an array like

ctrl.$parsers["f2"] but it does not return anything. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not have your functions numbered based on the index of your array then you could access them easier. So for example if f1 was your first function you could take the string "f1" and get the last number then subtract 1 from it and use that as the array index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over the array and inspect the function's `name` attribute:

```
function getNamedFunction(arr, name) {
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (arr[i].name === name) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

But `Function#name` [is not a standard property:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

> This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

A better (more compatible) approach would be to store your functions in an object:

```
var functions = {
   'f1': f1,
   'f2': f2,
};
```

and access it with

```
functions['f1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `name` prop and try this

```
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
 if (arr[i].name=='f2')....
}
```

Later you can use `splice` to remove the element.

`array.splice(index, 1);` ( returns the same array instance)

p.s.

This feature is non-standard

So what can you do ?

you can do this :

```
var g=[function f2(){},function f4(){}];

for (var i=0;i<g.length;i++)
{
  var m=g[i].toString().match(/function\s+(\w+)/i);

  if (m  && m[1]=='f4') alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `filter` method of the Array to select functions with a specific name

```
var myFunctions = [
    function a(){ alert(1); },
    function b(){ alert(2); },
    function c(){ alert(3); }
];

var someName = 'c'; // name of function to search for

// filter array checking the name property of each function in the array
var someFunction = myFunctions.filter(function(f){ 
    return f.name == someName; 
})[0]; // get the first function from the resulting filtered array

someFunction(); // alerts '3'
```